# Not working my submenu on ie8 & ie7 after using modernizr also?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

After also using modernizr.js, css3-mediaqueries.js, and HTML5shiv scripts, My submenu is not still opening in ie8 and ie7 on hover. Please help to sought out my problem . Here goes my menu code-

**HTML**

```
<nav>
<a class='responsive-menu' href='#' id='resp-menu'>

<div style='width: 35px; cursor: pointer; float: left ! important; box-sizing: border-box; transform: none ! important; background: rgb(246, 246, 246) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; margin-right: 10px; padding: 7px; margin-top: -7px; display: block; border: 2px solid rgb(228, 228, 228); border-radius: 3px; vertical-align: middle;'>
  <hr class='cb-ico' style='margin-top: 0px ! important;'/>
<hr class='cb-ico'/>
<hr class='cb-ico'/></div>Menu</a>    
   <ul class='menu' id='menu'>

<li><a class='homer' href='/'><i class='fa fa-home'/> HOME</a></li>
<li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-globe'/> INTERNET</a>
  <ul class='sub-menu'>
    <li><a href='/search/label/SEO'>SEO</a></li>
   <li><a href='/search/label/CSS'>CSS</a></li>
   <li><a href='/search/label/JQUERY'>JQUERY</a></li>
   <li><a href='/search/label/JAVASCRIPT'>JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
   <li><a href='/search/label/Downloads'>Downloads</a></li>
   <li><a href='/search/label/'>Sub-Menu 6</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'><i class='fa fa-wrench'/> WEB TOOLS</a>
  <ul class='sub-menu'>
   <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu 3</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu 4</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu 5</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Sub-Menu 6</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='/search/label/Tutorials'><i class='fa fa-comments'/> TUTORIALS</a></li>
     <li><a href='/p/contact.html'><i class='fa fa-envelope'/> CONTACT</a></li>
     <li><a href='/p/cr-sitemap.html'><i class='fa fa-sitemap'/> SITEMAP</a></li>
     <li><a href='/p/terms-of-service.html'><i class='fa fa-paperclip'/> TERMS OF SERVICE</a></li>
     <li><a href='/p/privacy-policy.html'><i class='fa fa-lock'/> PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>

<form action='/search' id='search' method='get' style='float:right;margin-right:2em'>
  <input name='q' placeholder='Search...' size='40' type='text'/>
</form>


</ul>
  </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  } body{font-size:15px;}


nav {
    display: block;
    background:#374147;
width:100%;
z-index:9999999;
 -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease 0s;
   -moz-transition: all 500ms ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease 0s;
     -o-transition: all 500ms ease 0s;
        transition: all 500ms ease 0s;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

}

.menu {
    display: block;
margin:0px;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.menu li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.menu li a {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
 transition: all 0.114s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.58, 0.57, 1) 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.114s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.58, 0.57, 1) 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.114s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.58, 0.57, 1) 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.114s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.58, 0.57, 1) 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.114s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.58, 0.57, 1) 0s;
}

.menu li a:hover,.menu li:hover > a {
   color: #fff;
    background: #9ca3da;
  }

.menu ul {
visibility: hidden;
-khtml-opacity: 0;
-moz-opacity: 0;
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-ms-filter: &quot;progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)&quot;;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 170px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
z-index: 99;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
top: 200%;
}

.menu ul:after {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 20%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: &quot; &quot;;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
}

.menu ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}



.menu ul li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    color: #797979;
    background: #fff;
}

.menu ul li a:hover,.menu ul li:hover&gt;a {
    background: #9ca3da;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu li:hover &gt; ul {
visibility: visible;
-khtml-opacity: 1;
-moz-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
-ms-filter: &quot;progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)&quot;;
top: 100%;
}
.menu ul ul {
left: 169px;
top: 0% !important;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}

.menu ul ul:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 10%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: &quot; &quot;;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-right-color: #fff;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}

  .menu li &gt; ul ul:hover {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
top: 0%;
}

.responsive-menu {
          display: none;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;,sans-serif;
    background:rgb(240, 240, 235) none repeat scroll 0% 0% !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAE9E9;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.responsive-menu:hover{
    background: #374147;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}


* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a.homer {
    background: #9ca3da;
}
```

Thanks! in Advance.

Comment: You're using a lot of CSS that isn't supported in IE8 and below, like transitions and different prefixed keys etc. Using modernizr doesn't really magically make old browsers do animations and stuff they don't support at all.

Comment: @adeneo is correct.  You could use modernizer to add your own new css for IE if you want.  just a simple li:hover .sub-menu {display: block} etc

Comment: But i want to use transitions in mozilla and other latest browsers , so what to do

Comment: Use a combination of javascript and add and remove classes, then you can use the transitions and they will fall back in older browsers to simply show and hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
-ms-filter: &quot;progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)&quot;;
```

above two lines was creating problems ... Now I Solve It.....